# Delete node from anywhere in a doubly linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I would like to delete a node from anywhere in a doubly linked list. But I hit an exception error. Could anyone help to solve the problem?
[Error Message sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3Iyn.png)

```
public void delete(T data) {
    /* if the list is not empty */
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        if (this.head == this.tail && data == this.head.data) {
            this.tail = this.head = null;
        } else if (this.head.data == data) {
            this.deleteFromStart();
        } else {
            DllNode temp = this.head;
            for (; temp != null & temp.data != data; temp = temp.next);

            if (temp != null) {
                if (temp == this.tail) {
                    this.deleteFromEnd();
                } else {
                    temp.prev.next = temp.next;
                    temp.next.prev = temp.prev;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code needed to reproduce the issue. It looks like the problem is not in this code, but in the code that builds/populates the list.

Comment: `temp != null & temp.data != data` don't use bitwise operators to join conditions - use `&&` for *logical and*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the error is in last line when `temp.next = null` so `temp.next.prev` will break. So you need to check if doesn't equal null before you access `temp.next.prev`.

Another point is try to avoid nested if conditions.
I refactored your code as below, but I didn't tested as you didn't share your class and the main function you used.

```java
public void delete(T data) {
    /* if the list is not empty */
    if (isEmpty()) return;
    if (this.head == this.tail && data == this.head.data) {
        this.tail = this.head = null;
        return;
    }  
    if (this.head.data == data) {
        this.deleteFromStart();
        return;
    } 
    DllNode temp = this.head;
    for (; temp != null & temp.data != data; temp = temp.next);
    if (temp == null) return;
    if (temp == this.tail) {
        this.deleteFromEnd();
        return;
    } 
    temp.prev.next = temp.next;
    if(temp.next == null) return;
    temp.next.prev = temp.prev;
}
```